# Bank statement and biometric date

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, proof-provenance-of-funds, biometric-passports

I am applying my UK visit visa and i have maintained good bank balance since a month which is enough for my trip. $6000 CAD and my trip cost $$2200 as i have my relatives for accommodation. My question here is, whether one month bank statement is ok? I need guidance as i dont have anyone who can help me here.

Secondly, i am submiting my application online on 6th july, do they start processing my application before my biometrics date or processing time is calculated after i give my biometric date? And does anyone have idea how long i have to wait for biometric date in toronto?

Thank you all

Comment: Just one bank statement doesn't give a picture of your finances. Maybe you really only have $50 but somebody lent you $5950 for a month to make your finances look better.

Comment: Thank you David Richerby for your answer, though thats not the reason i am keeping my one month. All money is mine as i am a full time workers since good time. The problem is my bank account is new and its only been opened since one and half month. So i asked if one month bank statement would be fine. I am also keeping my pay stub of three month and do you have idea of biometric

Comment: While not recent, I suggest you review this: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab?noredirect=1&lq=1 which discusses the significance of bank statements in visa applications, and interpretation of the information contained therein.

Comment: @Nick Unfortunately UKVI will wonder where the $6000 came from if they can’t reconcile your bank account entries with your stated sources of income. They will ask themselves where that amount of money came from - ‘I kept it in cash’ won’t be a good enough answer.